# How to improve wind data SQL query performance

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance, mariadb

I'm looking for help on how to optimize (if possible) the performance of a `SQL` query used for reading wind information (see below) by changing the e.g. the database structure, query or something else?

I use a hosted database to store a table with more than 800,000 rows with wind information (speed and direction). New data is added each minute from an anemometer. The database is accessed using a `PHP` script which creates a web page for plotting the data using Google's visualization API.

The web page takes approximately 15 seconds to load. I've added some time measurements in both the `PHP` and `Javascript` part to profile the code and find possible areas for improvements.

One part where I hope to improve is the following query which takes approximately 4 seconds to execute. The purpose of the query is to group 15 minutes of wind speed (min/max/mean) and calculate the mean value and total min/max during this period of measurements.

```
SELECT  AVG(d_mean) AS group_mean, 
        MAX(d_max) as group_max, 
        MIN(d_min) AS
        group_min, 
        dir, 
        FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(dt),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS group_dt 
FROM    (
    SELECT  @i:=@i+1, 
            FLOOR(@i/15) AS group_id, 
            CAST(mean AS DECIMAL(3,1)) AS d_mean, 
            CAST(min AS DECIMAL(3,1)) AS d_min, 
            CAST(max AS DECIMAL(3,1)) AS d_max, 
            dir, 
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')) AS dt 
            FROM table, (SELECT @i:=-1) VAR_INIT 
            ORDER BY id DESC
) AS T 
GROUP BY group_id
LIMIT 0, 360

...

$oResult = mysql_query($sSQL);
```

The table has the following structure:

```
1   ID      int(11)     AUTO_INCREMENT
2   mean    varchar(5)  utf8_general_ci
3   max     varchar(5)  utf8_general_ci
4   min     varchar(5)  utf8_general_ci
5   dt      varchar(20) utf8_general_ci    // Date and time
6   dir     varchar(5)  utf8_general_ci
```

The following setup is used:

- Database: MariaDB, 5.5.42-MariaDB-1~wheezy
- Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.66
- PHP version: 5.6
- PHP extension: mysqli

Comment: `5   dt      varchar(20) utf8_general_ci    // Date and time` Don't store date+time in a character field. Use datetime or timestamp (if available) And, similar for speed and direction: use integer, numeric, or even floating-point types, but **not** character types to store them.

Comment: Can you post an explain and data model? Also: Please format your code a bit so it becomes more readable.

Comment: A large part of your problem is probably the implicit conversions.  This also opens you up to unnecessary risk of error when querying.  With only 800k rows that might not be a huge deal, but it is still an issue.  And bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly agree with the comments so far -- Cleanse the data as you put it into the table.

Once you have done the cleansing, let's avoid the subquery by doing...

```
SELECT  MIN(dt) as 'Start of 15 mins',
        FORMAT(AVG(mean), 1) as 'Avg wind speed',
        ...
    FROM table
    GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt) / 900)
    ORDER BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt) / 900);
```

I don't understand the purpose of the `LIMIT`.  I'll guess that you want to a few days at a time.  For that, I recommend you add (*after* cleansing) between the `FROM` and the `GROUP BY`.

```
    WHERE dt >= '2015-04-10'
      AND dt  < '2015-04-10' + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

That would show 7 days, starting '2015-04-10' morning.

In order to handle a table of 800K, you would decidedly need (again, *after* cleansing):

```
INDEX(dt)
```

To cleanse the 800K rows, there are multiple approaches.  I suggest creating a new table, copy the data in, test, and eventually swap over.  Something like...

```
CREATE TABLE new (
    dt DATETIME, 
    mean FLOAT,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(dt)  -- assuming you have only one row per minute?
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO new (dt, mean, ...)
    SELECT str_to_date(...),
           mean, -- I suspect that the CAST is not needed
           ...;
```

Write the new select and test it.

By now `new` is missing the newer rows.  You can either rebuild it and hope to finish everything in your one minute window, or play some other game.  Let us know if you want help there.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being more clear on the details. Your assumptions regarding the use of LIMIT is correct.

Comment: I made a copy of the table and I followed your advices and changed both the data types in the table and rewrote the SQL query. Everything worked just fine. As for the performance, the query execute about 1 second faster so it's approx. 25% faster.

Comment: I missed the INDEX(dt) part. Could you please explain a little bit more what the purpose of this is? Is it a one time task by running a query like "CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name (column_name);"? Is the index something that I should use somehow or is it a database internal matter?

Comment: Is an index updated automatically as new data is added or do I have to manually reindex once in a while?

Comment: INDEXes are vital to high performance.  That index is useful because it will probably narrow down the number of rows to look at.  (I say "probably" because the optimizer may, legitimately, choose to scan the table instead of using the INDEX if the range covers 'too much' of the table.)  Yes, `CREATE INDEX` (or `ALTER TABLE..ADD INDEX..`) is a one-time task; it will take some time.  After that, the index will be updated automatically (and rapidly) when rows are INSERTed.

Comment: Thanks, I will add an index and see if it improves the performance. One last question (I hope): Are there any performance or other advantages in using WHERE over LIMIT? In my case I use LIMIT for pagination.

Comment: Note that a `PRIMARY KEY` is an `INDEX`, in particular, with the uniqueness constraint.

Comment: `LIMIT` needs an `ORDER BY`.  `LIMIT` would let you show the "last N items".  `WHERE` would do a similar task differently.  For Pagination, `LIMIT` (and `OFFSET`) gets slower and slower because it must step over the `OFFSET` rows.