# Speed up SQL SELECT with arithmetic and geometric calculations

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance, mariadb

This is a follow-up to my previous post [How to improve wind data SQL query performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29806192/how-to-improve-wind-data-sql-query-performance).

I have expanded the SQL statement to also perform the first part in the calculation of the average wind direction using [circular statistics](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_statistics#The_fundamental_difference_between_linear_and_circular_statistics). This means that I want to calculate the average of the cosines and sines of the wind direction. In my PHP script, I will then perform the second part and calculate the inverse tangent and add 180 or 360 degrees if necessary.

The wind direction is stored in my table as voltages read from the sensor in the field 'dirvolt' so I first need to convert it to radians.

The user can look at historical wind data by stepping backwards using a pagination function, hence the use of LIMIT which values are set dynamically in my PHP script.

My SQL statement currently looks like this:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(speed),1) AS speed_mean, MAX(speed) as speed_max,
       MIN(speed) AS speed_min, MAX(dt) AS last_dt,
       AVG(SIN(2.04*dirvolt-0.12)) as dir_sin_mean,
       AVG(COS(2.04*dirvolt-0.12)) as dir_cos_mean
FROM table
GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt) / 300)
ORDER BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt) / 300) DESC
LIMIT 0, 72
```

The query takes about 3-8 seconds to run depending on what value I use to group the data (300 in the code above).

In order for me to learn, is there anything I can do to optimize or improve the SQL statement otherwise?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I'm guessing you still use the same DB as in the question you linked to...

Comment: Can you run an `EXPLAIN` on that query?

Comment: Don't you want a "weighted" average in the circular statistics?  For example, when there is no wind, the gauge will be giving you a value, but do you really want that to dominate the result?  I suggest `AVG(speed*SIN(...))` etc.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the link.  I never thought about how to get the "average" bearing of the wind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table;
```

From that I can see if you already have `INDEX(dt)` (or equivalent).  With that, we can modify the `SELECT` to be significantly faster.

But first, change the focus from 72*300 seconds worth of readings to datetime ranges, which is 6(?) hours.

Let's look at this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE dt >= '...' - INTERVAL 6 HOUR
      AND dt <  '...';
```

The `'...'` would be the same datetime in both places.  Does that run fast enough with the index?

If yes, then let's build the final query using that as a subquery:

```
SELECT  FORMAT(AVG(speed), 1) AS speed_mean,
        MAX(speed) as speed_max,
        MIN(speed) AS speed_min,
        MAX(dt) AS last_dt,
        AVG(SIN(2.04*dirvolt-0.12)) as dir_sin_mean,
        AVG(COS(2.04*dirvolt-0.12)) as dir_cos_mean
    FROM  
      ( SELECT * FROM table
          WHERE dt >= '...' - INTERVAL 6 HOUR
            AND dt <  '...'
      ) AS x
    GROUP BY  FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt) / 300)
    ORDER BY  FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt) / 300) DESC;
```

Explanation:  What you had could not use an index, hence had to scan the entire table (which is getting bigger and bigger).  My subquery could use an index, hence was much faster.  The effort for my outer query was not "too bad" since it worked with only N rows.

Comment: Thank you Rick, I really appreciate your help! I did add dt as a primary index. After replacing the LIMIT (for geting only 6 hours of data) to your suggestion with a nested SELECT, the execution time for the query was reduced from 4.2 seconds to merely 0.008. Amazing! I will rewrite the pagination implementation to work with dt instead.